Unfolding an opaque fixpoint in Coq
I am currently solving Software Foundations and am in the IndProp chapter doing the excercise "filter_challenge". I have run into the following Problem in the merge_filter Theorem. Coq errors when I try to unfold the All fixpoint and says that it is opaque. I do not know why it is opaque.
I have tried to use cbv to compute the Fixpoint once but it did not work (and I am unsure on how to use it or if it even is the right tool for the job).
Here is my definition of merge:
Inductive merge {X:Type} : list X -> list X -> list X -> Prop :=
(* FILL IN HERE *)
| merge_nil : merge [] [] [] 
| merge_head l1 l2 l (x: X) (H: merge l1 l2 l) : merge (x::l1) l2 (x::l)
| merge_comm l1 l2 l (H: merge l1 l2 l) : merge l2 l1 l
.

My definition of All from Logic.v earlier in the book:
Fixpoint All {T : Type} (P : T -> Prop) (l : list T) : Prop
:= match l with
| [] => True
| x::l' => P x /\ All P l'
end.

The Theorem in question:
Theorem merge_filter : forall (X : Set) (test: X->bool) (l l1 l2 : list X),
  merge l1 l2 l ->
  All (fun n => test n = true) l1 ->
  All (fun n => test n = false) l2 ->
  filter test l = l1.
Proof.
  intros. 
  induction H.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl. unfold All in H0. 
  Admitted.

I want to unfold H0 to get a hypothesis regarding the head of the list.

You may need to recompile Logic.v to make your definition visible to IndProp.v instead of the original Admitted.

This was a problem with the build process. Rebuilding the project fixed it.

Please accept your own answer, so that it is clear that the problem is solved and how.

That "answer" is not an answer to the question posed "Unfolding an opaque fixpoint in Coq".  That behaviour makes it kind of pointless for the community to try to write clear and self-consistent answes to the questions.
It's nice to see that you found out what what causing your problem, though.

There is a vernacular keyword Transparent that makes an opaque definition transparent (and an Opaque that makes a definition opaque.  So you can do Transparent All. to make the definition of All unfoldable.
Opaque means  you can't look inside it, because you're not supposed to depend on its concrete definition.
Things defined with Qed. are set opaque, and things defined with Defined. are transparent, so simplification etc can expand them when necessary.
But you should know why you want to make an opaque thing transparent.
It's declared opaque for a reason.
